# Rename Model output names in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a series of tf.keras.Models that I have defined in the code below, which aims to solve a multi-task objective. The idea was to define the independent models, as well as a model which links all the inputs and outputs together.

However, while this model works, the output names of my targets are not named according to the targets, but rather the `multi_task_model` name defined in `multi_task_tower`. This means that the training losses are displayed as `multi_task_model_loss: 0.6166 - multi_task_model_1_loss: 0.5261 - multi_task_model_2_loss: 0.5257` instead of their target names.

How can I configure the final model so it outputs the 3 targets instead of a `multi_task_model (Functional)` model with 3 outputs? Is there a better way of doing this?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from typing import Dict, List, Optional

task_labels = ["label_x", "label_y", "label_z"]

input_a = tf.keras.layers.Input(name="input_a", shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32)
input_b = tf.keras.layers.Input(name="input_b", shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32)
input_c = tf.keras.layers.Input(name="input_c", shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32)

def tower_a(inputs = input_a):
  output_tower_a = tf.keras.layers.Dense(120)(inputs)
  tower_a_Model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, output_tower_a, name="tower_a_embedding")

  return tower_a_Model

def tower_b(inputs = input_b):
  output_tower_b = tf.keras.layers.Dense(120)(inputs)
  tower_b_Model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, output_tower_b, name="tower_b_embedding")

  return tower_b_Model

def tower_c(inputs = input_c):
  output_tower_c = tf.keras.layers.Dense(120)(inputs)
  tower_c_Model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, output_tower_c, name="tower_c_embedding")

  return tower_c_Model

def multi_task_tower(towers: List[tf.keras.Model], task_labels: List[str]):
  tower_inputs = [tf.keras.layers.Input(x.output_shape[1:], name=x.name) for x in towers]
  tower_models_concatenated = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(tower_inputs, name="tower_models_concatenated")
  outputs = {target: tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid", name=target)(tower_models_concatenated)
               for target in task_labels}
  
  # Build the model
  model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=tower_inputs, outputs=outputs, name="multi_task_model")

  return model


def build_complete_model(all_inputs: List[tf.Tensor], task_labels):

  input_a, input_b, input_c = all_inputs

  tower_a_model = tower_a(input_a)
  tower_b_model = tower_b(input_b)
  tower_c_model = tower_c(input_c)

  towers = [tower_a_model, tower_b_model, tower_c_model]
  mtt = multi_task_tower(towers=towers, task_labels=task_labels)

  # Create multi-tower model (connects body with head)
  multi_tower_model_output = mtt([tower_a_model.output, tower_b_model.output, tower_c_model.output])

  multi_tower_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[tower_a_model.inputs, tower_b_model.inputs, tower_c_model.inputs],
                              outputs=multi_tower_model_output,
                              name="multi_tower_model")
  
  multi_tower_model.compile(
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.01),
        loss={target: weighted_binary_crossentropy({0:1,1:1}) for target in task_labels}
  )

  return multi_tower_model, mtt, tower_a_model, tower_b_model, tower_c_model


# Get models
mtm, mtt, a, b, c = build_complete_model([input_a, input_b, input_c], task_labels)
```

```
>>>print(mtt.output_names)
['label_x', 'label_y', 'label_z'] 
>>>print(mtm.output_names)
['multi_task_model', 'multi_task_model_1', 'multi_task_model_2']
```

Multi-task model summary:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 tower_a_embedding (InputLayer)  [(None, 120)]       0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 tower_b_embedding (InputLayer)  [(None, 120)]       0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 tower_c_embedding (InputLayer)  [(None, 120)]       0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 tower_models_concatenated (Con  (None, 360)         0           ['tower_a_embedding[0][0]',      
 catenate)                                                        'tower_b_embedding[0][0]',      
                                                                  'tower_c_embedding[0][0]']      
                                                                                                  
 label_x (Dense)                (None, 1)            361         ['tower_models_concatenated[0][0]
                                                                 ']                               
                                                                                                  
 label_y (Dense)                (None, 1)            361         ['tower_models_concatenated[0][0]
                                                                 ']                               
                                                                                                  
 label_z (Dense)                (None, 1)            361         ['tower_models_concatenated[0][0]
                                                                 ']                               
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,083
Trainable params: 1,083
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Multi-tower model:

````
Model: "multi_tower_model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_a (InputLayer)           [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_b (InputLayer)           [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_c (InputLayer)           [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 dense_18 (Dense)               (None, 120)          240         ['input_a[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 dense_19 (Dense)               (None, 120)          240         ['input_b[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 dense_20 (Dense)               (None, 120)          240         ['input_c[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 multi_task_model (Functional)  {'label_x': (None,   1083        ['dense_18[0][0]',               
                                1),                               'dense_19[0][0]',               
                                 'label_y': (None,                'dense_20[0][0]']               
                                1),                                                               
                                 'label_z': (None,                                                
                                1)}                                                               
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,803
Trainable params: 1,803
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________```
````